# asp net core viewmodel parameter into string url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I would like passing a ViewModel parameter into url.

This parameter is an object inherit of

```
Dictionary<int, string>.
```

Into RC1, I can customize the url building with an override of "ToString" method :

```cs
public override string ToString()
{
    return String.Join("#", this.Select(d => d.Key + "|" + d.Value));
}
```

So the url have a value like this :

> myUrl?parameter=1|one#2|two

But since the last update into ASP NET Core 1.0, this not working, and no find other solution into the web.

Have you an idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why you want this? What you want to achieve from this ?

Comment: I just need passing my ViewModel with all values, include this Dictionnary.
And for that I used "RedirectToAction("Index", viewModel)".
MVC auto convert parameters for the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked to developers, and there is a workaround for this :
https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5093

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes